# Debugging a Rails app in Aptana/Eclipse

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, eclipse, aptana

I'm using the Aptana 3 plugin for Eclipse to do Ruby on Rails development.  I'm trying to use the ruby-debug-ide19 gem to do debugging within Eclipse.  I start a debug session by going to Run->Debug As->Ruby Application.

This works for the simplest of scenarios.  However, if I try accessing any of my models, classes in lib, etc, it won't work as my development environment is not being loaded prior to debugging.  How can I get my development environment to load before entering debug mode?  Just like what happens when I do a `rails console` on the command line.

If I can get this working, it looks like it'll be really nice.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I can't close my own posts yet, but all you need to do is require environment.rb at the top of the file to be debugged.  For example, I just did: require '/home/kyle/code/Portalconfig/environment'

Comment: hey @kstevens, you should actually write up your answer a bit more exhaustively and mark it as the correct answer. Good practice and helps others find it faster.

Answer (score 0):

I used Apatana for Rails development for a couple of years but ultimately switched to Rubymine from JetBrains. Rubymine's improved productivity, especially for debugging, made up for the $49 license in no time.

Comment: I agree 100%, I use their Intellij IDEA IDE (which RubyMine is based on), and it is great. I can spend more time developing and less time debugging and configuring my development tools.

Comment: Unfortunately you have to buy RubyMine and Aptana Studio is free.